# Allocate unique codes to records

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

We are being given a range of numbers which need to be used on some of our orders.

We must ensure that each number is allocated only once.
The range of numbers may be more than a million items (not sure at this stage how many digits but assuming less than 10).
I was thinking of prepopulating a table with these numbers so that every time one is used we can update that row with perhaps the orderid.

Table would be:
Id int, Code int, OrderId uniqueidentifier, Date datetime

When getting the latest number for allocating to an order we would find the `min(Code) where OrderId is null`

Id would be Primary Key but Clustered index will be set on Code column as that will be used for most important query.

Does this sound like a good way to go about doing this? Is there a better way?

Comment: *"When getting the latest number for allocating to an order"* What do you mean by this? Also, if you want the latest, wouldn't it be the max, or not min? Though this sounds like you might be reinventing the wheel, as `IDENTITY` and `SEQUENCE` exist.

Comment: The table would be prepopulated with rows.  orderid is null until the number has been allocated. numbers would be used starting at the lowest.  So to find the next number you would get the min(code) where orderid is null.  max code where orderis is null would give us the last row of the table.  But as you say I may be reinventing the wheel. Have not seen SEQUENCE before

Comment: _Is there a better way_ No one but you can answer that question. "Better" has no actual meaning and it depends greatly on what you measure, how rows are populated in your table, your abilities and concerns, future plans, etc. Perhaps you should think first about what happens when your range is exhausted. Typically people do not think of GUIDs (uniqueidentifier) as "numbers" - that is a concern.